# JS. How to replace html element with another element/text, represented in string?

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a problem with replacing html elements.

For example, here is a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="idTABLE">0</td>
        <td>END</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(it can be div, span, anything)

And string in JavaScript:

```
var str = '<td>1</td><td>2</td>';
```

(It can be anything, `123 text`, `<span>123 element</span> 456` or `<tr><td>123</td>` or anything)

How can I replace element `idTABLE` with `str`?

So:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="idTABLE">0</td>
        <td>END</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Becomes:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>END</td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<!-- str = '<td>1</td><td>2</td>'; -->

<table>
    <tr>
        123 text
        <td>END</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- str = '123 text' -->

<table>
    <tr> 
        <td>123</td> 
        <td>END</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- str = '<td>123</td>' -->
```

I tried `createElement`, `replaceChild`, `cloneNode`, but with no result at all =(

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but you can very simply `createElement` of, say, a `div` then set its `innerHTML` property.  I'd suggest using `jquery` for this if it's an option.  `$('<table></table>').append($('<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>'))` etc.  You have flexibility. with DOM manipulation.

Comment: It not always possible. For example, when create a div and set its innerHTML as '<td>123</td>', this div become '<div>123</div>' (js throws away inappropriate td tag)

Comment: Poster did not mention jquery and it is not necessary to do this.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As the Jquery replaceWith() code was too bulky, tricky and complicated, here's my own solution. =)

The best way is to use outerHTML property, but it is not crossbrowsered yet, so I did some trick, weird enough, but simple.

Here is the code

```js
    var str = '<a href="http://www.com">item to replace</a>'; //it can be anything
    var Obj = document.getElementById('TargetObject'); //any element to be fully replaced
    if(Obj.outerHTML) { //if outerHTML is supported
        Obj.outerHTML=str; ///it's simple replacement of whole element with contents of str var
    }
    else { //if outerHTML is not supported, there is a weird but crossbrowsered trick
        var tmpObj=document.createElement("div");
        tmpObj.innerHTML='<!--THIS DATA SHOULD BE REPLACED-->';
        ObjParent=Obj.parentNode; //Okey, element should be parented
        ObjParent.replaceChild(tmpObj,Obj); //here we placing our temporary data instead of our target, so we can find it then and replace it into whatever we want to replace to
        ObjParent.innerHTML=ObjParent.innerHTML.replace('<div><!--THIS DATA SHOULD BE REPLACED--></div>',str);
    }
```

That's all

Comment: I believe for most modern apps you can now safely use outerHTML: https://caniuse.com/#search=outerHTML

Comment: Agree, we can safely omit the `if` statement for `outerHTML`.

Related: [How to replace an element and its content using vanilla JS](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-replace-an-element-and-its-content-using-vanilla-js/)

Answer (score 11):

Using jQuery you can do this:

```
var str = '<td>1</td><td>2</td>';
$('#__TABLE__').replaceWith(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZBeW/4/

Or in pure javascript:

```
var str = '<td>1</td><td>2</td>';
var tdElement = document.getElementById('__TABLE__');
var trElement = tdElement.parentNode;
trElement.removeChild(tdElement);
trElement.innerHTML = str + trElement.innerHTML;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZBeW/1/

Comment: On the first look it looks like it work =). Thanks, I'll try your example

Comment: but it works only with first element. In <table><tr><td>start</td><td id="__TABLE__">0</td><td>END</td></tr></table> it works incorrectly.

Comment: That is true. The pure javascript way will not work in that case. The jquery version will. I think pebbl's answer #13388745 looks like a good pure javascript solution.

Comment: @EL2002 it sounds like what you are trying to achieve in some instances isn't actually possible (I've updated my answer accordingly)... that is if you are trying to add illegal HTML - I had just assumed you were stating some of your examples as theoretical. Thanks 3dgoo, your answer is perfectly fine solution for the initial examples given :)

Comment: @3dgoo: Ok, if you say JQ will do it, i'll try to extract replaceWith() function from JQ lib. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11):

Because you are talking about your replacement being *anything*, and also replacing in the middle of an element's children, it becomes more tricky than just inserting a singular element, or directly removing and appending:

```
function replaceTargetWith( targetID, html ){
  /// find our target
  var i, tmp, elm, last, target = document.getElementById(targetID);
  /// create a temporary div or tr (to support tds)
  tmp = document.createElement(html.indexOf('<td')!=-1?'tr':'div'));
  /// fill that div with our html, this generates our children
  tmp.innerHTML = html;
  /// step through the temporary div's children and insertBefore our target
  i = tmp.childNodes.length;
  /// the insertBefore method was more complicated than I first thought so I 
  /// have improved it. Have to be careful when dealing with child lists as  
  /// they are counted as live lists and so will update as and when you make
  /// changes. This is why it is best to work backwards when moving children 
  /// around, and why I'm assigning the elements I'm working with to `elm` 
  /// and `last`
  last = target;
  while(i--){
    target.parentNode.insertBefore((elm = tmp.childNodes[i]), last);
    last = elm;
  }
  /// remove the target.
  target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
}
```

example usage:

```
replaceTargetWith( 'idTABLE', 'I <b>can</b> be <div>anything</div>' );
```

demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/97H5Y/1/

By using the `.innerHTML` of our temporary div this will generate the `TextNodes` and `Elements` we need to insert without any hard work. But rather than insert the temporary div itself -- this would give us mark up that we don't want -- we can just scan and insert it's children.

...either that or look to using jQuery and it's `replaceWith` method.

```
jQuery('#idTABLE').replaceWith('<blink>Why this tag??</blink>');
```

#### update 2012/11/15

As a response to EL 2002's comment above:

> It not always possible. For example, when `createElement('div')` and set its innerHTML as `<td>123</td>`, this div becomes `<div>123</div>` (js throws away inappropriate td tag)

The above problem obviously negates my solution as well - I have updated my code above accordingly *(at least for the `td` issue)*. However for certain HTML this will occur no matter what you do. All user agents interpret HTML via their own parsing rules, but nearly all of them will attempt to auto-correct bad HTML. The only way to achieve exactly what you are talking about *(in some of your examples)* is to take the HTML out of the DOM entirely, and manipulate it as a string. This will be the only way to achieve a markup string with the following *(jQuery will not get around this issue either)*:

```
<table><tr>123 text<td>END</td></tr></table>
```

If you then take this string an inject it into the DOM, depending on the browser you will get the following:

```
123 text<table><tr><td>END</td></tr></table>

<table><tr><td>END</td></tr></table>
```

The only question that remains is why you would want to achieve broken HTML in the first place? :)

Answer (score 3):

You would first remove the table, then add the new replacement to the table's parent object.

Look up `removeChild` and `appendChild`

http://javascript.about.com/library/bldom09.htm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild

Edit:
jQuery .append allows sting-html without removing tags: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: It not always possible. For example, when createElement('div') and set its innerHTML as '<td>123</td>', this div becomes '<div>123</div>' (js throws away inappropriate td tag)

Comment: If you can use jQuery then the .append function will not do as you describe, I'll add to answer but appreciate you may not be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to actually replace the td you are selecting from the DOM, then you need to first go to the parentNode, then <strike>replace the contents</strike> replace the innerHTML with a new html string representing what you want. The trick is converting the first-table-cell  to a string so you can then use it in a string replace method.

I added a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vzUF4/

```
<table><tr><td id="first-table-cell">0</td><td>END</td></tr></table>

<script>
  var firstTableCell = document.getElementById('first-table-cell');
  var tableRow = firstTableCell.parentNode;
  // Create a separate node used to convert node into string.
  var renderingNode = document.createElement('tr');
  renderingNode.appendChild(firstTableCell.cloneNode(true));
  // Do a simple string replace on the html
  var stringVersionOfFirstTableCell = renderingNode.innerHTML;
  tableRow.innerHTML = tableRow.innerHTML.replace(stringVersionOfFirstTableCell,
    '<td>0</td><td>1</td>');
</script>
```

A lot of the complexity here is that you are mixing DOM methods with string methods.
If DOM methods work for your application, it would be much bette to use those.

<strike>You can also do this with pure DOM methods (document.createElement, removeChild, appendChild), but it takes more lines of code and your question explicitly said you wanted to use a string.</strike>

Comment: the result is: <table><tr><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr></table> and <td>END</td> will be lost

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks EL 2002 I didn't understand that we wanted to keep END, so we are turning a 2 column table into a 3 column. I'll update example.

Answer (score 1):

Your input in this case is too ambiguous.  Your code will have to know if it should just insert the text as-is or parse out some HTML tags (or otherwise wind up with bad HTML).  This is unneeded complexity that you can avoid by adjusting the input you provide.

If the garbled input is unavoidable, then without some sophisticated parsing (preferably in a separate function), you could end up with some bad HTML (like you do in your second example... which is Bad, right?).

I'm guessing you want a function to insert columns into a 1-row table.  In this case, your contents should be passed in as an array (without table, tr, td tags).  Each array element will be one column.

## HTML

```
<table id="__TABLE__"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

## JS

using jQuery for brevity...

```
function insert_columns (columns)
{
    var $row = $('<tr></tr>');

    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
        $row.append('<td>'+columns[i]+'</td>');

    $('#__TABLE__').empty(); // remove everything inside

    $('#__TABLE__').append($row);
}
```

So then...

```
insert_columns(['hello', 'there', 'world']);
```

## Result

```
<table id="__TABLE__"><tr><td>hello</td><td>there</td><td>world</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation. Here is my current code, since I couldn't do it better:

```
function update() {
            var game = $("a#customGame");
            games.forEach(updateGameList());
            
        }
        function updateGameList() {
            var i = 0;

            var game0 = $("span#game");
            var game1 = $("span#game1");
            var game2 = $("span#game2");
            var game3 = $("span#game3");
            var game4 = $("span#game4");
            var game5 = $("span#game5");                

            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    game0.innerHTML = "<a href='" + gameLink + "'>" + gameName + "</a>";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    game1.innerHTML = "<a href='" + gameLink + "'>" + gameName + "</a>";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    game2.innerHTML = "<a href='" + gameLink + "'>" + gameName + "</a>";
                    break;
            }
            
            i++;
            
            if (i > 5) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
```

It clearly is pretty bad. I am trying to use the `createElement` idea, but it failed. I am worried I am using the wrong function `innerHTML`. I hope this helps you guys.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35661862)

Answer (score -2):

use the attribute "innerHTML"

somehow select the table:

```
var a = document.getElementById('table, div, whatever node, id')
a.innerHTML = your_text
```

Comment: I mean replace entire element, not its innerHTML