# How can I replace some HTML tags between two specific elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```html
 <div class="header">A subject</div>
    <span class="start"></span>
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>a paragraph</p>
    <span class="end"></span>
    <div class="footer">a note</div>
```

Also I have a variable which contains some other tags like this:

```
var html = "<section> something <a href="#">my link</a> </section>;
```

All I want to do is replacing everything between `.start` and `.end` with `html` variable. How can I do that?

This is expected result:

```html
 <div class="header">A subject</div>
    <span class="start"></span>
    <section> something <a href="#">my link</a> </section>
    <span class="end"></span>
    <div class="footer">a note</div>
```

---

Since there isn't any wrapper, so I cannot use `.html()` or `.replaceWith()` functions. Is there any idea?

Comment: have a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388379/js-how-to-replace-html-element-with-another-element-text-represented-in-string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this you can select `.start`, then use `nextUntil()` to select the elements between that and `.end` before removing them. Then you can insert the new content after `.start`, like this:

```js
$('.start').nextUntil('.end').remove();
$('<section> something <a href="#">my link</a></section>').insertAfter('.start');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">A subject</div>
<span class="start">START</span>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>a paragraph</p>
<span class="end">END</span>
<div class="footer">a note</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow .. you have a great knowledge about jQuer . . .! upvote.

Comment: Just as a note, isn't using `nextUntil()` function slow? I don't know how it is implemented, but always I scare to use it. It seems to need lots of processing. Isn't it?

Comment: It will not be the fastest thing in the world, but should still be fast enough in 99% of cases. If you need ultimate performance I'd suggest not using jQuery at all as in some case it's orders of magnitude slower than native.

Comment: @MartinAJ it shouldn't... reasonably easy to take siblings, slice at start index then iterate remaining until selector found and break

Comment: @charlietfl I see. sounds like an optimized algorithm. thank you `:-)`

Comment: Fancy you! I was typing the exact same thing :) nice answer!

Comment: @LucasMedina Sorry I don't know English very well. Can you please tell me *"fancy"* means either a good thing there or bad?

Comment: It means a good thing. Just a compliment to @RoryMcCrossan's useful answer to your question!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use `.nextUntil()` method. It'll allow you to select a range of elements until the element specified as a parameter to the method.

`$('.start').nextUntil('.end')` will select every element from `.start` until `.end` (regardless of how musical this may sound).

After that, you can remove the selected elements and add the desired HTML with `.before()`.

```
$('.start').nextUntil('.end').remove();
$('.end').before(myHTMLVariable);
```

(For reference: https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)