# Cannot read property 'style' in Element[]

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

TypeScript. document.elementsFromPoint return `Element[]`, but the 'Element' does not contain such a property as "style". As a result, i'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.

How to change the style of the 'Element' in the TypeScript.
My code:

```
document.body.onclick = function(event: MouseEvent) {
            let elements: Array<HTMLElement> = document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY) as Array<HTMLElement>;
            let divs: Array<HTMLElement> = [] as Array<HTMLElement>;
            for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if(elements[i].tagName == 'DIV') {
                    divs.push(elements[i])
                }
            }
            if (divs.length == 2) {  // before if OK
                console.log('2 divs!!! Unit is here!');
                let flag: string = document.body.getAttribute('flag');

                if (flag != '1') {
                    document.body.setAttribute('flag', '1');
                    divs[2].style.backgroundColor = "rgba( 255, 1, 0, 0.5)";
                }
                else {
                    document.body.setAttribute('flag', '0');
                    divs[2].style.backgroundColor = "rgba( 255, 1, 0, 0.5)";
                }
            }

        };
```

Comment: Array indices start at 0

Comment: Arrays are zero-based; divs[2] is undefined

Comment: Usually I do not allow such gross errors. Excuse me. But how to upgrade my divs now?

Comment: for upgrade new div: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388379/js-how-to-replace-html-element-with-another-element-text-represented-in-string

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `upgrade` new divs.  Change `divs[2]` to `divs[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking that the length of your `divs` array is 2, and then you attempt to read from the 3rd array element (arrays in JavaScript are zero-indexed).

Try changing it to `divs[1]`

Comment: I apologize for my inattention. But how to upgrade my divs now?