# Within a markup-string, how to replace any e.g. class-name specified element with its own title-text?

Tags: javascript, html, markup, domparser

I have a variable called `$text`.

I want to make it so that if there are any spans with the class "emote", replace the entire span and its contents with the title attribute of the span. Also, it must be case sensitive.

If `$text` had this as a value:

```html
<p>blah blah blah <span class="emote" title="bOOger"> blah blah blah</span></p>
```

It would become this:

```html
<p>blah blah blah bOOger</p>
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Which approach would the author choose? Is there already any code which shows what the OP did try? Also the chosen text within before and after makes the goal a little ambiguous.

Comment: @PeterSeliger regex might be a solution? But I don't know regex at all.

Comment: How about [`DOMParser.parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)? jQuery actually is not needed.

Comment: Convert it to a DOM element via [`.parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) and then perform HTML manipulation on that: [Create a text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode), insert it after the span, then remove the span.

Comment: Convert to DOM element as others have noted, then use the answers to [JS. How to replace html element with another element/text, represented in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13388379/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function replaceAnyTargetedElementByItsTitleText(markup, selector) {
  const doc = (new DOMParser)
    .parseFromString(markup, "text/html");

  doc
    .body
    .querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach(node => node
      .parentNode
      .replaceChild(
        document.createTextNode(node.title),
        node,
      )
    );

  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

const markupBefore =
  '<p>foo bar baz <span class="emote" title="bOOger">quick brown fox</span></p>';

const markupAfter =
  replaceAnyTargetedElementByItsTitleText(markupBefore, '.emote');

console.log({ markupBefore, markupAfter });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Impressive! What a pro