# How can I convert one html element to another element?

Tags: javascript, wechat-miniprogram

Recently I have been coding the WeChat mini program.

There are some HTML strings will get from the remote server (these strings are also used by the website, so it has to convert by JavaScript) and render into the body of the mini program.

Whereas, WeChat mini program cannot accept the HTML strings that I have to convert it.

For example, the HTML strings are like this:

```
<div>
   <h2 id="Title">Here is a H2</h2>
   <article class="ContentArticle">
   There are some articles.
   </article>
</div>
```

I have to convert them like this:

```
<view class="div">
   <text class="Title h2">Here is a H2</text>
   <text class="ContentArticle article">
   There are some articles.
   </text>
</view>
```

In my first opinion, I consider achieving this by `String.replace` method. However, it can hardly match the `class` and `id`.

How can I achieve this by using the original JavaScript (the WeChat mini program does not support any other library such as jQuery)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS. How to replace html element with another element/text, represented in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388379/js-how-to-replace-html-element-with-another-element-text-represented-in-string)

Comment: @AndersonGreen It is something similar to my question. Let me try it. Thank you.

Comment: What level of nesting do you anticipate. 1 like the example you posted. Or unlimited?

Comment: @Bravo The nesting is unknown but not unlimited. Most of times is 2 or 3.

Comment: What did you try in order to solve this yourself, where did you get stuck? Where's your "*[mcve]*" code, what went wrong with that and in what way?

Comment: The component "rich-text" may help u.
For example: <rich-text nodes="..html code" />
It will render the html code.

Comment: @taolu in spite of it is an easy way. However, it is not friendly for SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that will transform any html code received from your backend into the desired format. No matter what kind of and how many elements
are encountered, they will be converted into `<text`> elements with `.className`s composed of their `id` (if available), their original `.className` and their original `.tagName` (in lower case):

```js
const htmlArr=[`<div>
   <h2 id="Title">Here is an H2</h2>
   <article class="ContentArticle">
   There are some articles.
   </article>
</div>`,
`<div>
   <h2 id="Title">Here is another H2</h2>
   <article class="ContentArticle">
   And here are some more.
   </article>
</div>`,
`<div>
   <h3 id="Title">Here is an H3 heading</h3>
   <article class="ContentSubArticle">
   This is a sub-article.
   </article>
</div>`];

document.body.innerHTML=htmlArr.map(d=>{
 let div=document.createElement("div");
 div.innerHTML=d;
 return '<view class="div">'+[...div.children[0].children].map(e=>`<text class="${((e.id||"")+" "+e.className).trim()} ${e.tagName.toLowerCase()}">${e.innerHTML}</text>`).join("")+'</view>';
}).join("\n");

console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
```

`htmlArr` is an array with possible html strings. In the snippet above all strings are converted and then put on the page by using `document.body.innerHTML`. This was merely done for demonstration purposes. The conversion output can of course be used in different ways